# ASP.NET Core MVC Download request `FileResult` giving error on Azure app service

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

In ASP.NET Core MVC app I'm trying to download a file by returning `FileResult`

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    var fileName = $"DM.jpg";
    var filepath = $"download/{fileName}";
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
    return File(fileBytes, "application/x-msdownload", fileName);
}
```

it's working fine on localhost but when I publish the app on Azure its not working and says "An error occurred while processing your request".
[image: error]
How can I know what's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To troubleshoot this issue, please try:

1.[Turn off customErrors](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2014/05/22/azure-web-sites-troubleshooting-server-error-in-application-errors) to get helpful error message

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

2.[Enable diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log#overview) for your Azure App Service web app and check logs.

3.[Remote Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure) on your asp.net core.